# Redirect specific sub directory to new url in Ingress

Tags: kubernetes-ingress

I need to redirect a specific URL to a new one.
I can use this code to redirect root domain but it doesn't work for subdirectory likes testdomain.com/specific-url

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
  if ($host = 'testdomain.com/specific-url') {
    return 308 https://testdomain.com/new-url;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use below approach I suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51424712/9929015).
And copy paste for future:

My advice is to use [NGINX Plus Ingress Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51424712/9929015) annotation functionality if you can afford it.

You can find [official  example here](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/master/examples/rewrites).

Example:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: cafe-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.org/rewrites: "serviceName=tea-svc rewrite=/;serviceName=coffee-svc rewrite=/beans/"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: cafe.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /tea/
        backend:
          serviceName: tea-svc
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /coffee/
        backend:
          serviceName: coffee-svc
          servicePort: 80
```

Below are the examples of how the URI of requests to the  `tea-svc`  are rewritten (Note that the  `/tea`  requests are redirected to  `/tea/`).

```
/tea/  ->  /
/tea/abc  ->  /abc
```

Below are the examples of how the URI of requests to the  `coffee-svc`  are rewritten (Note that the  `/coffee`  requests are redirected to  `/coffee/`).

```
/coffee/  ->  /beans/
/coffee/abc  ->  /beans/abc
```